# Qt - How to test whether the text of QTableWidget item is an integer number or not not?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtablewidget

I am working with the Qt and C++. If I have a `QTableWidget`, how can I test if an item's text is an integer?

```
if(table->item(index, 0)->text().is_integer())
    Qdebug("yes is an integer") ;
else 
    Qdebug("no is not an integer") ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like you do the usual `QString` to `int` conversion - [`QString::toInt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt), but you can ignore the return value. I suggest this helper function, because of the way `QString::toInt` gives you know about the success/failure:

```
bool isInt(QString const& str, int base = 10)
{
    bool ok = false;
    str.toInt(&ok, base);
    return ok;
}
```

Usage:

```
if(isInt(table->item(indice, 0)->text()))
    ...
```

**Edit:** I don't know why I used `toInt` here. If there are bigger numbers only representable with larger integer data types (or you want to deal only with `unsigned` numbers), make this function for those.